# la funcion socket en python es simplex (de un solo camino)?

Tags: python

```
import socket
s = socket.socket()
s.connect(("localhost", 9999))
s.listen(5)
sc, addr = s.accept()
while True:
    recibido = sc.recv(1024)
    mensaje = raw_input("> ")
    s.send(mensaje)
    print(recibido)
    if mensaje=="exit":
        break
print "fin de conecxion"
s.close()
```

Comment: No se si te he entiendo correctamente,  ¿te refieres a que la comunicación es en un solo sentido? Un socket es bidireccional (aunque podemos no usarlo como tal). Lo que si que ocurre es que en un socket bloqueante como el tuyo `recv`es bloqueante, va a **quedarse esperando hasta que le llegue algo** del cliente... Por otro lado tu server acepta hasta  5 clientes, pero para poder manejarlos simultáneamente  tienes que usar hilos o corrutinas.

Comment: si exacto a eso me refería, osea que en teoría para que funcione el envió desde el servidor tiene que iterar entre recv y send?